# Match all '^0xCD' before first occurence of '^0xDD'

Tags: regex

I need  to perform multiline search that matches all `0xCD` at the beginning of a line up to the first occurence of `0xDD` also at the beginnig of a line.

I tried with this `(?s)^0xCD(?=.*?^0xDD)` but it just matches all `^0xCD` even those after `^0xDD`.

I am using `Sublime Text 3` editor with regular expressions enabled.

Input

```
0xCD 0xAA 0xBB
0xAA 0xBB
0xCD 0x78
0xAA 0xBB
0xDD 0xBB
0xCD 0xBB
0xDD 0xA4
0xCD
```

As an output I expect ST3 to find two matches of `0xCD`. The one at line `1` and the one at line `3`. The real file indeed is much bigger and the number of ocurences showed into the status bar of the ST3 when the regex match will spare me a lot of counting. 
0xAA 0xBB

Comment: Please provide some input text you deal with. Are you just searching, or are you trying to remove/replace these strings?

Comment: Try `(?s)\G(?:(?!0xDD).)*?\K0xCD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `\G` based regex:

```
(?s)\G(?:(?!0xDD).)*?\K0xCD
```

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - an inline DOTALL modifier making `.` match line break symbols, too
- `\G` - an anchor that matches at the start of the string and then after each successful match
- `(?:(?!0xDD).)*?` - a tempered greedy token matching any char that is not a starting point for a `0xDD` character sequence, matched in  a lazy way, that is, the pattern is skipped first, and the subsequent patterns are tried first, and only when they fail to find a match, this token is "expanded" (if you remove `?` the token won't work well)
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all the text matched so fat during the current iteration
- `0xCD` -  the substring to be matched and "returned" as a match.